# A product of a column vector with identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Can some one help me to multiply the left hand side of this equation, a column vector with the identity matrix, the right hand side is just a number, i don't have a problem with it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is a column vector, then $xI_d$ is not well defined as the matrix multiplication is not well defined.

$$I_dx = x = x\cdot I_1$$